# Invalid (negative) timestamp after grouping Ktable by key

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using KakfkaStreams (**2.3.0**) to do some value enriching using a join between a Stream and a Ktable (compacted topic).
The issue is that the compacted topic is being written to using a different partitioner that the stream topic so the join is not working as expected (some keys don't match because they're in different partitions).

Broker version is 0.10.2.

I started looking into re-partitioning the compacted topic by using a **groupBy()** followed by a **reduce()** but when it starts reading the re-partition topic created, it starts throwing a **StreamsException** with the message:

> Input record ConsumerRecord(topic = mappings-table-repartition, partition = 18, leaderEpoch = null, offset = 0, CreateTime = -1, serialized key size = 37, serialized value size = 20, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = 0cecdec3863208e57, value = (1126999878035640323<-null)) has invalid (negative) timestamp. Possibly because a pre-0.10 producer client was used to write this record to Kafka without embedding a timestamp, or because the input topic was created before upgrading the Kafka cluster to 0.10+. Use a different TimestampExtractor to process this data.

The repartition is being created and populated automatically by KafkaStreams so this seems weird that it would write an invalid record.
I even tried supplying a custom Timestamp extractor when reading the initial compacted topic but it didn't do any difference. The stacktrace seems to indicate that it's using an internal TimestampExtractor (and looking at the code it is indeed)

> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.FailOnInvalidTimestamp.onInvalidTimestamp(FailOnInvalidTimestamp.java:73)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.ExtractRecordMetadataTimestamp.extract(ExtractRecordMetadataTimestamp.java:61)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.FailOnInvalidTimestamp.extract(FailOnInvalidTimestamp.java:48)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.updateHead(RecordQueue.java:167)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:100)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:136)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:746)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addRecordsToTasks(StreamThread.java:1023)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:861)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:805)
>       at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:774)

The code is something like this:

```
KTable<String, String> table = streamsBuilder
                .table(mappingsTopic,
                       Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String(),
                                      null,
                                      Topology.AutoOffsetReset.EARLIEST))
    .groupBy(KeyValue::pair,
             Grouped.with("mappings-table", Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
   .reduce((value1, value2) -> value2, (value1, value2) -> value2)
```

Comment: Sorry, added it right now

Comment: The compacted topic (source of KTable) is being created by a go kafka client, but don't know the version.
The topic for the stream is being written using 0.10.2.
The service is using the clients from KafkaStreams 2.3.0, so I'm guessing the repartition topic is being written with 2.3.0

Comment: Could you add properties used for KafkaStreams?

Comment: `props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "application");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "broker:9092");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 1000);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.TOPOLOGY_OPTIMIZATION, StreamsConfig.OPTIMIZE);`

Comment: I'm trying to replicate with a local broker (2.10-0.10.2.1). 
Made a "copy" of the compacted topic using console-consumer and piping to console-producer (both version 2.1.1) and I don't get the null timestamp issue BUT it is very very slow reading the topic, meaning it takes almost 30 mins to read and do the grouping + reducing while just creating the table from the compacted topic takes 1 min (+/-)

Comment: So the performance issue in the local machine is due to the cache in the in-memory-store materialization of the reduce operation. Disabling the cache made the performance go up to acceptable levels (1-2 mins)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198576/discussion-between-wardziniak-and-antonio-dias).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message indicates, you need to upgrade the message format your brokers use (cf. broker config `log.message.format.version`)

As of Kafka Streams 1.0, a message format 0.10 or newer is required.

From: https://kafka.apache.org/23/documentation/streams/upgrade-guide

> Note, that a brokers must be on version 0.10.1 or higher to run a Kafka Streams application version 0.10.1 or higher; On-disk message format must be 0.10 or higher to run a Kafka Streams application version 1.0 or higher. For Kafka Streams 0.10.0, broker version 0.10.0 or higher is required.

Kafka Streams tries to set the record timestamp on write, however, older message format does not support timestamps (on write, the timestamp is lost when the message format is downgraded). Hence, on read a dummy timestamp `-1` is put into the message when the message format is converted back.

It's not allowed to set a different timestamp extractor for repartition topics, because upstream timestamps must be forwarded downstream for correctness.